# Script that delete files after 5 days

Tags: server, scripts

Is it possible to make a script that will delete files in a specific folder, after five days without deleting the folder(s).

I am using Ubuntu server 12 without `gui` interface.

Answer (score 11):

To find files last modified more than five days ago:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -mtime +4
```

To delete them at the same time (***test the above first***):

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -mtime +4 -delete
```

To automate it so that you're running this daily, run `crontab -e` (as the user you wish to run this task) and add:

```
@daily find /path/to/directory -type f -mtime +4 -delete
```

---

An experiment to show which `mtime` value you want to use. The manual is rubbish. I had assumed `+5` was what we wanted but a comment disagreed. The documentation appears to conflict so I started by creating three files, each 1 day apart:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/now
$ touch -d "1 day ago" test/yesterday
$ touch -d "2 days ago" test/day-before-yesterday
$ ls -l test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli 0 Nov 26 13:12 day-before-yesterday
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli 0 Nov 28 13:11 now
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli 0 Nov 27 13:12 yesterday
```

If we want something that is between 24-48 hours old exactly, we use 1 without a sign.

```
$ find test -mtime 1
test/yesterday
```

But if we want things 24hours +, `+1` doesn't work:

```
$ find test -mtime +1
test/day-before-yesterday
```

`+1` seems to mean "more than what `1` shows"... So `+0` is used:

```
$ find test -mtime +0
test/day-before-yesterday
test/yesterday
```

All very annoying if you're used to being correct like me... But I'll recover, I'm sure. Thanks for the poke from Adaephon.

Comment: It probably should be `-mtime +4`. `-mtime +5` would mean 'modified more than 5 days ago' and as any fractional parts are ignore that is essentially 'modified at least 6 days ago'.

Comment: @Adaephon The `man find` definition is really bloody confusing. The [GNU docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html) say the same things but also give examples. `1 means “between 24 and 48 hours ago”` would suggest that using `+5` is correct. It means `at least 5x24 hours old`.

Comment: yes it really isn't that clear. But the meaning of `+n` is "more than n" not "at least n" and as fractions are ignored, this means that `+1` means "more than 48 hours ago". This also means that if you want to say "more than one day ago" you have to write `+0`. From the ubuntu man page on find: `to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.`

Comment: @Adaephon I decided to do a quick test to prove it one way or the other. Long story short: Congratulations, you've won an internet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, use cron jobs
Suppose you need to remove files in /tmp/test/ directory after five days then

```
crontab -e
```

now add these lines to the last

```
@weekly rm -fr /tmp/test/
```

Now the folder will be deleted weekly.
For more info click [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like

```
@weekly find /tmp/test -type f -exec rm '{}' +
```

Note: just rm -rf removes folders too. You could add -mtime for modification time.

Does it has to be five days exactly. Get your favorite days or times in:

Minute  - Hour  - Day of Month  - Month -  Day of Week

```
0 3 0,5,10,15,20,25 * *
```

Which means 3 AM each five days unless the month is 31 days.