# find -mtime not working

Tags: command-line, files

I tried all the suggestions in the article:
[Script that delete files after 5 days](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383331/)

When I run find without the `-mtime` parameter it finds the files I am looking for.  When I add `-mtime +2`, nothing is returned. I know there are files of the appropriate date(s) in the directory I am looking in with the `find` command.

Comment: What is the `8.04` tag on the bottom of your question? I am running Ubuntu 19.04 and `find` version is `4.6.0.225-235f`. What is the output of `find --version` in your system? What command exactly are you using?

Comment: 8.04? are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

From `man find`:

```
 -atime n
          File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find  figures  out  how  many  24-hour
          periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match
          -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

 -mtime n
          File's  data  was  last  modified  n*24  hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to
          understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.
```

but see also:

```
  -daystart
          Measure  times  (for  -amin,  -atime,  -cmin,  -ctime,  -mmin, and -mtime) from the
          beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago.  This option only  affects  tests
          which appear later on the command line.
```

In summary, use `find -mtime +1` to find 2 day old files.